# Why is this string value converted to an array?

Tags: ruby

I have the following function:

```
def parse_var(var)
    value = instance_variable_get(var)
    puts(value)
    puts(value.to_s)
    value.is_a?(Numeric) ? value.to_s : "\"#{value}\""
end
```

Variables of certain form are converted into an array when they are interpolated. In the above function, when `value` equals `(684) 029-6183 x01024`, `value.to_s` comes out to be `["(684) 029-6183 x01024", nil]`. The same thing also happens when I try `"#{value}"`.

What is causing this?

Here's the context of the code in question:

**Entity.rb (context of above code)**

```
require 'securerandom'

# Entity.rb
class Entity
    def initialize
        generate_uuid
    end

    def to_cypher
        first_char = self.class.name.chr.downcase
        "MERGE (#{first_char}:#{self.class.name} {#{attrs_to_cypher.join(', ')}}) RETURN #{first_char};"
    end

    protected

    def rand_bool
        [true, false].sample
    end

    private

    def attrs_to_cypher
        self.instance_variables.map do |var|
            "#{camelize(var.to_s[1..-1])}:#{parse_var(var)}"
        end
    end

    def generate_uuid
        @uuid = SecureRandom.uuid
    end

    def parse_var(var)
        value = instance_variable_get(var)
        puts(value)
        puts(value.to_s)
        value.is_a?(Numeric) ? value.to_s : "\"#{value}\""
    end

    def camelize(s)
        (s == "uuid") ? "UUID" : s.downcase.split('_').map(&:capitalize).join
    end
end
```

**PhoneNumber.rb (where the value is coming from)**

```
require 'faker'
require_relative 'Entity'

# PhoneNumber.rb
class PhoneNumber < Entity
    def initialize(**opts)
        super()
        @type         = opts[:type]         || rand_bool ? "cell" : "home"
        @number       = opts[:number]       || @type == "cell" ? Faker::PhoneNumber.cell_phone : Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number,
        @country_code = opts[:country_code] || nil
        @area_code    = opts[:area_code]    || nil
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line of code is causing a couple of issues

```
@number = opts[:number] || @type == "cell" ? Faker::PhoneNumber.cell_phone : Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number,
```

First, the `||` operator has a higher precedence than the `?` operator, so it actually looks like:

```
@number = (opts[:number] || @type == "cell") ? Faker::PhoneNumber.cell_phone : Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number,
```

and you probably were wanting this:

```
@number = opts[:number] || (@type == "cell" ? Faker::PhoneNumber.cell_phone : Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number),
```

As it stands, it doesn't matter what you pass into `opts[:number]`, you'll always get a `Faker::PhoneNumber` assigned. (The line above, assigning type, looks like it would have this same precedence issue)

Second, you have a stray comma at the end of the line. This is turning the entire line into the first element of an array, and doesn't interfere with assigning the variable on the next line, so it's hard to catch:

```
opts = { number: '123' }
type = "cell"
number = opts[:number] || type == "cell" ? "truthy" : "falsey",
country = "some value"

p number  # => ["truthy", "some value"]
p country # => "some value"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable contains `["(684) 029-6183 x01024", nil]`, not a string. You rely on `puts(value)` output to determine it’s value which is plain wrong:

```
puts ["(684) 029-6183 x01024", nil]
#⇒ (684) 029-6183 x01024
#
```

`puts(nil)` returns an empty string, making you think the original value is a string.

To overcome this issue you might:

```
value = [*value].compact.join
```